# Should the Service be stopped when not in use?

Tags: android, android-service

I am coding an application which will trigger some action (like toast message) every 5 minute after the Screen is ON. I have made a 'Service' for this purpose. My Service is running successfully and triggering the specified action every 5 minutes.
My 'Service' keeps on running even when the Screen is OFF. I don't want to perform any action when the Screen is OFF. Should I stop the service on every screen OFF and re-run it on the next screen ON? or should I keep it running even when the Screen is OFF?
I just want to decrease the load on CPU performance because of the background running 'Service'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the service keep running, and display the Toast only if the screen is off using following code,

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
```

Now,

```
if ( isScreenOn )
{
        // Display Toast
}
else
{
        // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: Whats the reason for -1 ?

Comment: will keeping the 'Service' running in background cause any load on the performance? I just want to decrease any unwanted load.

Comment: It was by mistake -1..sorry

Comment: It depends what work your service does. If your service is not doing too much work and using resources then why to stop & start service again & again.

Comment: You dont have enough rep to do -1 on my answer. How you did it ?

Comment: I thought I did -1 by mistake. But It was not me then.